# Install pool Package

Tags: r, database, shiny, package, cran

Trying to install the Pool package with th following command

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"devtools::install_github("rstudio/pool")\""
```

But I get the following error message:

```
> devtools::install_github(rstudio/pool)
Error in lapply(repo, github_remote, username = username, ref = ref, subdir =subdir,  :
 object 'rstudio' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> -> lapply
Execution halted
```

Info: I have the most recent DBI package installed and many more packages without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your quotes do not quite work the way you want. Try

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"devtools::install_github('rstudio/pool')\""
```

replacing `"` arond `rstudio/pool` with `'`